# how to show that how much rating is given to a particular item into your project

Tags: java, android, iphone

I am android developer and  working on a project based on hotel room booking and I wanted to show the ratings of all the different  hotels individually so that the customer user could find out easily about the best choice in hotels. 
I know how to make a rating bar but to show how much rating has been given to each and every hotel, I am a bit confused about this, if anyone could guide me the whole tutorial, I shall be very thankful that how to put those .... like

for example.
a particular hotel will have 3 star another one have 3.5 star... in that way !! the data I know will be definitely coming from API but How To Show The RATINGS of the hotels .

I am putting the data in the list view ,

- 1st  Image of Room,
- 2nd  Name of Hotel,
- 3rd  Rating of the hotel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using RatingBar also to view the result

and set there the value by:

```
rate_bar.setRating(2f);
```